# Generating a sequence perturbed by non-stationary white noise

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

I want to create a list of numbers that would come form a process in which each number depends on the past value and a white noise. But I'd like the white noise to be non-stationary in the mean; the mean should go up with every period.

Here's what I came up with, but it's only with a stationary white noise:

```
SeedRandom["série5"]
série5 = 
  Flatten @ 
    NestList[
      0.5*# + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 1], 1]&, RandomReal[], 10]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't `FractionalBrownianMotionProcess` and `FractionalGaussianNoiseProcess` be employed?

Comment: @Karsten7. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Different approaches using [functional iteration](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionalIteration.html), all resulting in the same output.

```
SeedRandom["série5"];
série5 = Block[{m = 2 - 0.1}, 
  NestList[0.5*# + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[m += 0.1, 1]] &, RandomReal[], 10]]
```

---

```
SeedRandom["série5"];
série5 = 
 NestList[{0.5*#[[1]] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#[[2]], 1]], #[[2]] + 0.1} &, 
  {RandomReal[], 2}, 10][[All, 1]]
```

---

```
SeedRandom["série5"];
série5 =
 FoldList[0.5*#1 + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#2, 1]] &, RandomReal[], 
  Range[2, 2.9, 0.1]]
```

---

```
SeedRandom["série5"];
série5 =
 FoldList[0.5*#1 + #2 &, RandomReal[],
  Array[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, 1]] &, 10, {2, 2.9}]]
```

---

```
SeedRandom["série5"];
série5 =
 SequenceFoldList[0.5*#1 + #2 &, {RandomReal[]},
  Array[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, 1]] &, 10, {2, 2.9}]]
```